# Jenkins parameterized build when creating a tag

Tags: build, jenkins, parameterized

Is there a way to hook into/trigger a build after I click the "tag this build" link?

I'd like to do the following:
1. click 'tag this build' (on a successful build, of course) manually, and enter the tag name/url (i.e. RELEASE-v1.0.0)
2. use a regex or something to get the version number (1.0.0) and pass that to a build.

I'd like to do this all from clicking the 'tag a build', if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't quite do what you describe, but the [Promoted Builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) might be what you need; it lets you mark a build and then run additional build steps.